# numpy change value of cyclic range of elements

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of elements, for simplicity:
`array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])`.
Starting with 0, every nth element, I'd like to change the value of the next m elements.
For example: `n=5; m=2` and I'd like to set the elements to 100.


The output should be something like: 
`array([ 100,  100,  2,  3,  4,  100,  100,  7,  8,  9, 100, 100, 12, 13, 14, 100, 100, 17, 18, 19])`

is this a numpy way to do it in one line (with indices)? or only by looping or list comprehension - which will be slower..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following could do the job

```
arr.reshape((-1, n))[:, :m] = 100
```

Comment: If you want to learn more about ways of slicing numpy arrays, I recommencement to read the following: https://towardsdatascience.com/advanced-numpy-master-stride-tricks-with-25-illustrated-exercises-923a9393ab20